# Graphics driver problem: full grey screen

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

My laptop GPU integrated is: Intel HD Graphics 3000 Sandybridge.
The dedicated one is Nvidia Geforce GT 630M 2GB.

I installed Ubuntu Gnome 15.10 on this laptop. I installed all the updates from the software updater. Then I restarted the PC.
I selected as additional driver the the Nvidia binary driver - version 352.63 (proprietary, tested). Then I restarted the PC.
I downloaded and installed Intel Graphics installer from here: https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.2.1. After installation I updated. Then I restarted the PC.
As primary GPU I use the Intel.

However, after all this, I got from time to time some grey screens for 2-5 seconds and then it comes back, even when I use as primary GPU the Nvidia one.

How can I solve this problem? Please HELP!

PS: I am new GNU/Linux user. Thank you!

Comment: Go to ttyl1 and try sudo prime-select intel

Comment: Info: the current alternatives in use are: ['nvidia-352-prime', 'nvidia-352-prime']
Info: the intel profile is already in use

Comment: Sudo service lightdm restart

Comment: Failed to restart lightdm.service: Unit lightdm.service failed to load: No such file or directory.

Comment: Sudo apt-get install - -reinstall lightdm

Comment: I installed it. I hope it works... Do i have to type sudo service lightdm restart now? What should I do if I still get grey screens? Thank you very much!

Comment: Try the restart command

Comment: When the problem persists or now after the lightdm installation?

Comment: After the installation

Comment: Ah, ok. What should I do after the restart? Sorry but I am very noob at this.

Comment: I'm assuming it still isn't working

Comment: If I get a new grey screen I will come back with a reply. The problem is that from time to time i get the grey screens. I cannot control when or how will happen. Anyway thank you very much for your effort!

Comment: Is there any way I can skip the login screen? I want to use only the gnome 3 DE.

Comment: That should be a different question, so you can ask again. As for help to anyone who has a similar problem in the future, I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm 

sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: i think the problem is solved, can you explain to me what happened with that command? what did it changed and what was the problem before that? thank you again!

Comment: One of the components of your lightdm package was corrupted, likely deleted by some other operation.

Comment: oh... well that is so stupid because grey screens started after the clean install...

Comment: Hello again, it seems the lightdm didn t worked because the problems are back, specially when I open multiple chrome tabs with videos like youtube videos. Any other ideea? thank you!

Comment: Your graphics card is probably crashing.

Comment: Type about://flags and deselect soft 3D rendering

Comment: bash: about://flags: No such file or directory

Comment: Try this on a terminal
"google-chrome --disable-gpu"